# Using values from separate classes method

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a rough skeletal project I created, but with my limited knowledge I am trying to do a few things I am not sure of..

I am trying to use methods from a separate class to basically do my calculations, storing for my main class (using main class to just display outputs while my num class stores and calculates, etc.)

At the momment the user can choose a number and it does get stored into double rad but I'm not sure how to move that over to my other classes (num) method called number.

```
            string radIn = "";
            double rad;

            bool rslt = false;

            while(rslt == false) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
                radIn = Console.ReadLine();
                result = double.TryParse(radIn, out rad); 
                if(rslt == false) 
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number only"); 
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                else 
                {
                    do
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("(1)Your number");
                        Console.WriteLine("(2)Update number");
                        Console.WriteLine("(3)Calculate");

                        string userC = Console.ReadLine();

                        switch (userC)     //==============Issue focused here===========
                        {

                            case "1": 
                                //number user has chosen here, not sure how to grab it from my other class
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                //Updated user number output here
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                //Calculating method output appearing here
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.Clear();
                                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice!");
                                break;
                        }                 //===========================================
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    while (true);
                    break;
                }
```

In a separate class I have a num class where I'm trying to do most of my work:

```
 class num
    {
        public int number()
        {
            //trying to store user picked number here
        }
        public void set()
        {
            //trying to do the required steps to changing and updating the users number here and storing  
              in the number method
        }
        public double calculation()
        {
            //calculation (number * 10) result supposed to be displayed when user selects 3
        }
    }
```

I apologize if my code is a bit jumbled, I've tried a few searches but I don't think I've been able to word exactly what I'm looking for correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Need to modify few places and it's done.

```
//Change the class slightly as to store a value and calculate
class num
{
    public double number { get; set; }

    public double calculation()
    {
        //calculation (number * 10) result supposed to be displayed when user selects 3
        return number * 10;
    }
}
```

Create a new instance outside of while-loop

```
var enteredNumber = new num();
double rad;
```

Use variable in your switch statement as

```
switch (userC)     //==============Issue focused here===========
{
    case "1":
        enteredNumber.number = rad;
        break;
    case "2":
        //Updated user number output here
        Console.WriteLine("Value is :{}", enteredNumber.number);
        break;
    case "3":
        //Calculating method output appearing here
        Console.WriteLine("Value is :{}", enteredNumber.calculation());
        break;
    default:
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Choice!");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you change the signature of the **num** class to be like the code below this will allow you to reference it in Main.cs

```
public static class num
{
    public static int number() { }

    public static void set() { }

    public static double calculation() { }
}
```

Then in Main.cs the following should work.

```
num.set()
num.number()
num.calculation()
```

The keyword **static** is important to understand.

Comment: Using `static` to store state is generally a bad idea and will cause dragons in your code the more you use it.

Comment: agreed. Considering the question I made an assumption that OP may not fully understand how to create objects, that is why I suggested using static, because it was one of the first things I learnt before I learnt about new-ing up objects etc.